# How to boostrap angularJS 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In order to bootstrap in Angular 1.XX we have

```
ng-app ="myApp"
```

and in Js file, we write

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

How can we bootstrap in Angular 2?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html ? It is a little bit more complex than 1.x

Comment: I will take a look to this link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and the following command.

```
npm install -g angular-cli    
ng new PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: '<h1>My application</h1>'
})
class App{}
bootstrap(App);
```

It's the simplest way to bootstrap your application. But good practice is to separate your components and bootstrap file.
Check this small video course: https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-say-hello-world-to-angular-2?course=angular-2-fundamentals